# IndexOf moving throughout a string is not identifying characters (Java)

Tags: java, string, object, twitter, indexof

I am working on a Twitter-type program in Java where the body is the the tweet that is being sent out. I am trying to use indexOf to find the positions of the hashtag and the position of the white-space, so that I can print out all of the hashtags, through concatenation, with one call to the accessor. When I am running the program I get an out of bounds error for the line :

```
allHashtags+=bodyTemp.substring(position, space+1)+" ";
```

I have tested the sub-string and the problem seems to be related to the "position" variable, but I am not sure how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
 public String getAllHashtags() {
        int indexFrom=0;
        int position=0;
        String allHashtags="";
        String bodyTemp=body;
        while(position>-1) {
            position=bodyTemp.indexOf("#");
            int space=bodyTemp.indexOf(" ");
            allHashtags+=bodyTemp.substring(position, space+1)+" ";
            bodyTemp=bodyTemp.substring(space+1);
        }
        return allHashtags;
    }
```

example body: "Hello #world How are #you"

allHashtags= "#world #you"

If something is unclear about the code/my explanation, please let me know and I will try to clarify it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why aren't you just using a regex? And are you meaning to concatenate to `allHashtags` rather than just overwrite it? And why use `bodyTemp=bodyTemp.substring(space+1);` rather than just supplying the second parameter to `indexOf`?

Comment: Well if one of the method calls indexOf() returns -1 because the string doesn't contain either "#" nor a space " " then you will try to get a substring from or up to a negative location.

Comment: @Andy Turner I am not using a rejex because I am not allowed to. Yes, I am trying to concatenate (I just updated to code because I had not copied the correct lines). I am not sure what you mean by your last question.

Comment: @JKostikiadis The strings all contain hashtags and spaces in different positions.

Comment: To find the problem try to debug your code by inserting println statements printing the variables position , space and bodyTemp.length. In order to get IntexOutOfBoundException one of the first has to be wrong or you have surpass the string length. In addition the +1 at the end of the substring index is not safe cause if for some reason the String ends with "#" you will try to take access up to string.length instread of length -1

Comment: The last hashtag does not have a space after it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First way by using split to take all the words and after check if each one of them starts with "#"

```
public static String getAllHashtags() {

    String body = "Hello #world How are #you";
    String tokens[] = body.split("\\s+");
    String allHashtags = "";

    for (String token : tokens) {
        if (token.startsWith("#")) {
            allHashtags += token; 
        }
    }
    return allHashtags;
}
```

Another way using a while loop and search for indexes of hashtag :

```
public static String getAllHashtags() {

    String body = "Hello #world How are #you";
    String allHashtags = "";

    int index = -1;
    while ((index = body.indexOf('#')) != -1) {
        // cut the string up to the first hashtag
        body = body.substring(index+1);
        // we need to check if there is a empty space at the end or not
        if(body.indexOf(' ') != -1) {
            allHashtags += "#" + body.substring(0,body.indexOf(' '));
        }else {
            allHashtags += "#" + body;
        }

    }
    return allHashtags;
}
```

P.S it's 3am don't expect optimal code at least for today :P

**Important** : if the words are separated by tabs or new line the second code will obviously not going to work :P that;s why I like/prefer the first one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You were very helpful!